# Using Variables defined in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a problem where a script already contains variables set by the user for example:

```
$_Name = "AU"
$_Description = "AU Security"
```

I want to use these variables in a CSV file and Import the data where PowerShell recongnises the Variables and displays the value of the Variables. For example (CSV):

```
ou,description,path
Security,$_Country Security,"OU=$_Name,$_DomainDN"
Servers,$_Country Servers,"OU=$_Name,$_DomainDN"
Database,$_Country Database Servers,"OU=Servers,OU=$_Name,$_DomainDN"
```

When importing the CSV file using something like:

```
$csv - Import-Csv .\Test.csv
```

The CSV is imported, but the variable `$csv` literally contains the Variable name and not what is stored in the Variable already set.

Is there anyway I can achieve what I want? I tried wrapping the Variable names in `$( )`, `${ }` and `@( )` without success.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ExpandString`:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\Test.csv

$csv | % { 
    $_.description = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_.description); 
    $_.path = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_.path); 
    $_ 
    }
```